# How to set up WordPress 3.0 with Domain Names (w/Directories)

Tags: wordpress, mapping, subdomain

I am trying to use a single WordPress 3.0 installation to set up multiple blog sites that have unique domain. I am vaguely familiar with WordPress MU Domain Mapping Plugin.

**Is there any way to do the following:**

> blogs.rootdomain.com/site1 -> sub1.rootdomain.com/blog
>
> blogs.rootdomain.com/site2 -> sub2.rootdomain.com/blog

(with all the links on the pages resolving to this path root)

I have seen numerous examples with MU Domain Plugin resolving to a domain root. But in my case, I was existing sub-domains that a separate blog.

Answer (score 1):

No. Domain Mapping requires that the WordPress instance either be a subdomain or a subdirectory. It is not possible to mix the two.

It must be either:

```
sub1.rootdomain.com
sub2.rootdomain.com
```

Or

```
rootdomain.com/site1
rootdomain.com/site2
```

For more info on Multi-Site, I gave a presentation recently and you could browse my slides:

http://jgill.me/wcslc2012

Comment: Note, as you have posted above, the rootdomain.com/site method can have any variation of www or subdomain but that must remain constant across all /site1 /site2 setups. Make sense?